# How to build Variable Array

Tags: c#, arrays, variables

I am starting to learn C# using visual studio in WPF form and so my coding knowledge is very limited language-wise but very advanced in terms of understanding.

I have dealt with arrays before but that was ages ago. I can recall however the simple mp3 playlist tag array:
"Song name", "Artist", "Year", etc. I recall discussing how it was possible to make it dynamic but that knowledge was lost.

Here is my situation:

I want to build a program that can call upon specific X and Y array points and bring up entire lines.

Here's an example:
In code I would like to declare a string array where the following positions are denoted:

```
[var0, var1, var2, var3]
```

I want to then use a pre-built array based on that previous "key" so that positions 0,1,2 and 3 are linked to those variables.

Then, in the program itself, the idea is that when I call var1, it outputs var0, var1, var2 and var3 from the specific array horizontal row.

Here's another example using the same previous key:

```
["Never gonna give you up", "Rick Astley", "1990", "Troll"]
["Together forever", "Rick Astley", "1990", "Pop"]
["99 Red Balloons", "Nena", "1998", "German"]
["Can't get you out of my head", "Kylie Minogue", "1995", "Pop"]
```

I want to look up in position #2 all elements matching "Rick Astley"; output should be:

```
["Never gonna give you up", "Rick Astley", "1990", "Troll"]
["Together forever", "Rick Astley", "1990", "Pop"]
```

If I change the list, however, the variables are still held the same way unless I change they key.

Thank you

PS: I don't want anyone to make the whole program, just how to declare the variables and find the key variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

This will allow you to store a class or variable on each key.

**Example:**

```
    var variables = new Dictionary<int, string[]>();
    variables.Add(0, new string[] { "Never gonna give you up", "Rick Astley", "1990", "Troll" });
    variables.Add(1, new string[] { "Together forever", "Rick Astley", "1990", "Pop" });
    variables.Add(2, new string[] { "99 Red Balloons", "Nena", "1998", "German" });
    variables.Add(3, new string[] { "Can't get you out of my head", "Kylie Minogue", "1995", "Pop" });

    foreach (var variable in variables.Where(v => v.Value.Contains("Rick Astley")))
    {
        foreach (var text in variable.Value)
        {
            Console.Write($"{text}, ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    Console.Read();
```

**Output:**

```
Never gonna give you up, Rick Astley, 1990, Troll,
Together forever, Rick Astley, 1990, Pop,
```